# Need to show Store name under Order grid

Tags: multistore, store-id

I am New to Magento. I have a live Magento site (1.9.3.8). The previous developer created Store name and store views.

Currently having 2 store's  1. default 2. mobile.

If the customer places the order via PC then Store information will be stored as default and if the customer place the order through mobile then store name will be mobile in the order grid column "Purchased From (Store)".

But this functionality is not working. only default store is saving all the time.

I have created folder mobile under root folder and copied all the required files and in `Index.php` i put

```
Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'mobile';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

If I am wrong. Please guide me how to achieve this. I need to show order came through mobile or Website.

Thanks.